# Using CASE expression in condition of Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, stored-procedures

Suppose there are 2 table 'Source' and 'Name'. And the records of table are as:

**Source table**

[image]

**Name table**

[image]

My SQL query is:

```
select s.* 
from source s 
join name n on 
    s.Market = n.Market
    and s.Owner = n.Owner
    and s.Name = n.Name
    and Source = case Source when 'State' then 'State' else 'Data' end
```

[image]

And it returns 2 records but I have to use the 'State' if it exists and ignore the 'Data' and if 'State' is not there then use 'Data'.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the ON clause.

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: Are those you expected results? Or your current incorrect results? And whats the logic behind that case expression? Is it part of the join condition? the where clause and if so whats it trying to do?

Comment: I have updated with my expected result. The logic of the case expression will be like if in table, 'State' is present then only that record will return and ignore the 2nd record having 'Data' but if 'State' is not present then it will use 'Data'. And yes it is a part of join condition.

Comment: To get your desired results just use `where s.Source = 'State'`? No case required?

Comment: According to your last comment shouldn't market `B` be part of your expected output?

Comment: According to the records present and join condition market B will not return.

Comment: OK, I think I get it, but you might want to expand your sample data to include the case where no 'state' record exists - because currently thats not covered by your sample data. Also for future reference if you could present your data as formatted text, instead of images. DDL/DML statements which create test data would be ideal.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: You don't seem to understand joins or your case. JOIN ON 1st CROSS JOINs  then keeps those rows that meet the ON. Decide what row pairs you want to keep & put the condition in the ON. Your last case conjunct is condition `s = (if s='s' then 's' else 'd')`, ie `if s='s' then s='s' else s='d'`, ie `if s='s' then true else s='d'`, ie `s='s' OR s='d'`. Is that the condition that ANDed with the others keeps a row? What is? PS [mre] When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without a join.
Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function and `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  s.Market, s.Owner, s.Name,
  FIRST_VALUE(s.Source) OVER (PARTITION BY s.Market, s.Owner, s.Name ORDER BY CASE WHEN s.Source = 'State' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) Source 
FROM Source s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Name n WHERE n.Market = s.Market AND n.Owner = s.Owner AND n.Name = s.Name)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=636d86f372ab3742e7757b8ed58020bf).
Results:

```
> Market | Owner | Name | Source
> :----- | :---- | :--- | :-----
> A      | ADMIN | NM_1 | State
```